# Rounding number up or down based on given range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was given a requirement, which is a rounding a number up or down to the configured range of number.

For example, a range of 0 to 50. Rounding up will round up the number to 50 while rounding down will round down the number to 0.

**Test cases for range of 0-50**

```
49060 --> Round up 49060 | Round down 49060
49020 --> Round up 49050 | Round down 49000
```

**Test cases for range of 50-100**

```
49060 --> Round up 49100 | Round down 49050
49050 --> Round up 49100 | Round down 49050
49049 --> Round up 49049 | Round down 49049
```

So i developed the following code

```
function rounding( a ){

    // Assume that a is a number
    var amount = a.toString(),
        roundType = 'up', // or down
        min = 0, max = 50, // This is the range
        splitVal = parseInt( amount.substr( -max.toString().length ) ),
        obj = {};

    // If splitVal is smaller than min or bigger than max,
    // then rounded up will yied its own value
    if (max > splitVal || splitVal < min){
        obj.total = a;
        obj.rounding = 0
    }

    // If split value is between min and max
    if (max > splitVal > min){
        obj.total = a + ( max - splitVal );
        obj.rounding = max - splitVal;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

It works for test cases of range 0-50 but not for range 50-100.. especially if a is 49950, and the range is 50-100, and its rounded up.

Where did i make mistake here?

Comment: give us an example of couple of number e.g. 39.23 => 39 and 51.24 => 52 and 1920.24 => 1920 and 1920.24 => 1921 is this what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Given this example `49050 --> Round up 49100 | Round down 49050` should it round down or up?

Comment: Also `49060 --> Round up 49060 | Round down 49060` appears to round to the nearest 10, yet `49020 --> Round up 49050 | Round down 49000` rounds down to the nearest 50...?

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov it is rounding any part of the number to that max (if round up) or min (if round down) of the number. If the range is between 0 - 49.99, any number with last 2 values of between that range like 1230, 1242445, 14449.98 will be rounded up to 49.99 or rounded down to 0.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i gave two example there, the range is 50-100, so if we round up 49050, the 50 part of 49050 is between 50-100 ( 50 >= 50 >= 100 ), so we round it up to 100, which turns the number into 49100. If we try to round it down, since 50 is the min number of the range, so there is no change, so its still 49050.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan For range 0-50, you dont look at the whole number, instead you look at the last 2 digits (can be more depending on the range which can extend till hundreds and thousands). In the case of 49060, you look at the 60 part, and since 60 is not between 0-50 range, so rounding it has no effect at all. It has to be in between the range for it to round up to the max range, or round down to the min range. For range of 0-50, 49060's 60 is not in between the 0-50, but 49050's 50 is between 0-50 (50 >= 50 >= 0) so rounded down to the min range which is 0. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to find a top value for later finding the remainder value for checking, if this is in the wanted range.

If not return the original value (in this code, only one value is returned, instead of two values as down and up rounded value).

If in the wanted range, return a base value plus the lower range and the base value plus the upper range.

```js
function round(value, range) {
    var top = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.max(...range)))),
        mod = value % top,
        base = value - mod;

    return mod < range[0] || mod > range[1]
        ? value
        : range.map(r => base + r);
}

console.log(round(49060, [0, 50]));    //  49060   49060
console.log(round(49020, [0, 50]));    //  49000   49050
console.log(round(49060, [50, 100]));  //  49050   49100
console.log(round(49050, [50, 100]));  //  49050   49100
console.log(round(49049, [50, 100]));  //  49049   49049
console.log(round(49140, [0, 50]));    //  49100   49150
console.log(round(499955, [50, 100])); // 499950  500000
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like your implementation. However your implementation doesn't work for numbers like 49140 or 499930 if we take range of 0-50. 49140 rounded up between range 0-50 will become 49150 and rounded down to 49100, while for range 50-100, rounding up 499955 will become 50000 and rounding down will become 499950.

Comment: do you want to have a look to two or three last digits? please add the wanted values for `499930` with `0-50` and `499955` with `50-100`.

Comment: Yea it will look to the last amount of digits based on the range. For example for range 0-100, for numbers like 40151, it can look for any from 151, 51 or 1 and round it up. In this case 40151 rounded up with range of 0-100 will become 40200, while rounded down will become 40100. For your number 499930 with 0-50 range, rounding up will become 499950 while rounding down will become 499900. For 499955 with range 50-100, rounding up will become 500000 while rounding down will become 499950,

Comment: Yeap.. so far this has fulfilled all my test cases. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the modulus operator (%) with 100 for that. Then, with reminder I'd determine which range is in case, and with another parameter in function ('up' or else) i'd calculate the final result.

Here is the test function (testen only on couple numbers, it may break, but the idea is the key):

```
function r(x,type) {
  let res = x%100;
  let result;

  if(res < 50) {
    if(type === 'up') {
        result = x + (50 - res);
    }
    else {
        result = x - res;
    }
  }
  else {
    if(type === 'up') {
        result = x + (100 - res);
    }
    else {
        result = x - res;
    }
  }

  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: res can be const as it's not reassigned

Comment: Sure, code could be further optimized, it's just a quick sketch of an idea

Comment: @MirzaMašić i like the idea of using modulus to get to the number that we want to check and round up but how can we know what should we divide it to? Say the range is like 140-249 or 399-499?

Comment: @FredA well, for this specific request, the range was 0-50 and 50-100, hence we use 100. We could adjust the function and add third parameter that would be the range, and replace all instances of 100 in the function with the new parameter, and 50 with new parameter / 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is lesser code and easy to understand

```
function rounding(a,rangeA,rangeB){
    total = Math.abs(rangeA - rangeB) * Math.round(a / Math.abs(rangeA - rangeB))
    return (rangeA < a || a < rangeB)?{total: total, rounding: Math.abs(a - total)}:{total: a, rounding: 0}
}
```

More shorter

```
function rounding(a,rA,rB){
    m=Math;b=m.abs;r=b(rA-rB);t=r*m.round(a/r);return(rA<a||a<rB)?{total:t,rounding:b(a-t)}:{total:a,rounding:0};
}
```

Edit: Fix the code

Comment: Your code doesnt work if the value is 49051 for range 50-100.